# Parsing a PCAP file - Why does this packet header timestamp contains SOH \01?

Tags: haskell, pcap, packet-capture, packet-sniffers, packets

I'm extracting the first 4 bytes from a pcap packet header, which should represent a quantity of seconds. Here they are, in order of appearance in the ByteStream (I'm using Haskell):

```
\192    (192)
\166    (166)
x       (120)
SOH     (01) (Start of Header)
```

My understanding is that the four bytes can be read as a 32-bit integer. However, the presence of SOH is throwing me off. If I interpret the 4 bytes as one integer, I get 2 billion, which is invalid (2 billion seconds = 63 years => invalid because UNIX times starts in 1970, about 45 years ago).

The packet header also ends with NUL (00).

I'm also not sure why the four bytes are reversed, maybe a side-effect of how I'm pulling bytes from the stream (using a Get function and getInt32). Shouldn't the SOH come first?

Comment: Maybe PCAP is big-endian ("network" order) or little-endian? Check whether you have `getInt32BE` or `LE` available in your library.

Comment: There actually is a useful blog walk-though of the format, motivated by someone writing a Haskell parser - http://www.kroosec.com/2012/10/a-look-at-pcap-file-format.html

Answer (score 1):

Did you check the magic number at the very beginning of the pcap file? Its purpose is 1. identify the file format; 2. allow you to determine the byte order. Here's a handy reference: https://wiki.wireshark.org/Development/LibpcapFileFormat#File_Format